# Cursor doesn't show on tinymce set focus

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm trying to have a hint overlay on a tiny mce text editor. When the user clicks on the hint I want to set the focus on the tiny mce editor.

It seems that when I use

```
tinyMCE.get('editor-text').focus();
```

the focus is set but I can't see a cursor. How can I get the cursor to show?

This show's the problem. Click on the text. I'm using latest Chrome.
http://jsfiddle.net/u6XCL/

```
$(function(){
    $('#overlay').mousedown(function() {
        $("#overlay").hide();                
        tinyMCE.get('editor-text').focus();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the mouseup event here. See the modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cLrtA/

```
$(function(){
    $('#overlay').mouseup(function() {
        $("#overlay").hide();                
        tinyMCE.get('editortext').focus();
    });
});
```